# How can I fix the following sed command?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, replace, sed

I am trying to append `_out` to anything that matches the regex shown in the follwing sed command. The `_out` should be before the `[ (]`.

```
sed -n '/[^_]lm[01?]_.*[ (]/p'
```

The command returns the lines correctly as I expect. Now the problem comes when I try the following command where I define regions to use in the replacement.

So for example if I have a match of `lm?_whatever(` it should be replaced by `lm?_whatever_out(`.

I used

```
sed 's/\([^_]lm[01?]_.*\)\([ (]\)/\1_out\2/g' text_to_edit
```

And as you might guess I was unlucky. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is an example explaining more:

The text:

```
this will make absolutely no sense=lm?_hello <= four_lm1_hi(5:0) bla bla
lm1_blabbering(5:0)
```

should turn into

```
this will make absolutely no sense=lm?_hello_out <= four_lm1_hi(5:0) bla bla
lm1_blabbering_out(5:0)
```

Comment: post some sample input and desired output, we are not supposed to decipher this regex :)

Comment: your seond regex is ``_.*`` while the first one is ``_*.``. Major change!

Comment: It is because of `[^_]`. Remove it. Do you really need it?

Comment: @Vincent My first regex was  typo while i was copying , my question still stands.

Comment: @stribizhev, I guess I do, how else could I get it done ? otherwise in the example above `four_lm1_hi(5:0)` will be replaced. The negation worked in the first command though.

Comment: I guess you can use `sed 's/\([^_]lm[01?]_[^[:blank:]]*\)\([ (]\)/\1_out\2/g' text_to_edit`. Please check.

Comment: @stribizhev, That worked, (with some bugs because my example is not complete) but thanks! I still don't get why though... Mind to explain ?

Comment: @AshrafMohamedOsama: Since it worked, I am posting an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to only match your `lm` words and not affect the following ones, you need to restrict the pattern. I suggest turning `.*` to `[^[:blank:]]*` to match *0 or more characters other than spaces or tabs*:

```
sed 's/\([^_]lm[01?]_[^[:blank:]]*\)\([ (]\)/\1_out\2/g' text_to_edit
```

*(EDIT)* Or, if the only characters there are between `_` and  are alphanumeric characters, you may use `[[:alnum:]]` character class:

```
sed 's/\([^_]lm[01?]_[[:alnum:]_]*\)\(.\)/\1_out\2/g' text_to_edit
```

This way, we'll make sure only the `lm?_hello` and `lm1_blabbering` are matched.

Comment: Please let me know what bugs you encountered.

Comment: The bugs are simple (my fault for the incomplete example), nothing that I can't figure out. You solved the main issue. Thanks

Comment: `sed 's/\([^_]lm[01?]_[[:alnum:]_]*\)\(.\)/\1_out\2/g' text_to_edit` is what worked best for me